# OkHttpClient hangs after receiving 202 while making a follow-up request

Tags: kotlin, okhttp

I'm trying to make a "resumeable" PUT request to upload a file to backend using OkHttpClient. Here's the workflow:

Split the file into 5 MB chunks. For every chunk, upload it to backend. Successful chunk upload is signified by 202, except for the last chunk, which returns 200.

Here's the code that works with URLConnection:

```
val sessionUuid = UUID.randomUUID()
var readSoFar = 0
var connection: HttpsURLConnection? = null
file.forEachBlock(CHUNK_SIZE, action = { buffer, bytesRead ->

    val contentRange = "bytes $readSoFar-${readSoFar + bytesRead - 1}/${file.length()}"
    val url = URL(token.url)
    connection = url.openConnection() as HttpsURLConnection
    connection.doOutput = true
    connection.addRequestProperty("Content-Range", contentRange)
    connection.addRequestProperty("Session-Id", sessionUuid.toString())
    token.fields.entries.forEach { (key, value) -> connection.addRequestProperty(key, value) }
    connection.requestMethod = "PUT"
    connection.connect()
    connection.outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead)
    status = connection.responseCode
    readSoFar += bytesRead
}
```

And for a 14 MB file, we get 202, 202, and 200 from backend.

Here's the code using `OkHttpClient`:

```
val sessionUuid = UUID.randomUUID()
var readSoFar = 0
file.forEachBlock(CHUNK_SIZE, action = { buffer, bytesRead ->
    val contentRange = "bytes $readSoFar-${readSoFar + bytesRead - 1}/${file.length()}"

    val requestBuilder = Request
        .Builder()
        .url(token.url)
        .method("PUT", RequestBody.create(null, buffer))
        .addHeader("Content-Range", contentRange)
        .addHeader("Session-Id", sessionUuid.toString())

    token.fields.entries.forEach { (key, value) -> requestBuilder.addHeader(key, value) }

    val response = okHttpClient.newCall(requestBuilder.build()).execute()
    status = response.code
    response.close()
    readSoFar += bytesRead
}
```

The first chunk is uploaded successfully with a 202. The second chunk hangs and request ends by throwing `SocketTimeoutException` every time.

Any idea why the 2nd request that's made with `OkHttpClient` is hanging? I've tried increasing all the timeouts to 6 minutes, the request still doesn't go through.

**August 24, 2021 Update**

Finally got the time to look into this, and thanks to J.Gerbershagen's suggestion, I was able to get it working by changing the RequestBody to:

```
buffer.toRequestBody(offset = 0, byteCount = bytesRead)
```

Comment: Share the stack trace?

Comment: Is the RequestBody content identical? In your first example the `buffer` from 0 to `bytesToRead` is written to the request body. In your second example, the full buffer is written to your request body.

Comment: @J.Gerbershagen thanks, your suggestion was spot on. If you want, you can create a post and I'll mark it as correct answer!